# Running two Google Analytics properties for same domain

Tags: google-analytics

I am about to setup cross-domain tracking to connect 3 different domains.

**Domain #1** - Primary Informational Domain

**Domain #2** - eCommerce for the primary domain

**Domain #3** - User portal for the primary domain

I am a bit hesitant to implement the cross-domain tracking on the property that tracks the primary domain only at the moment. I want to test things out a bit first plus I will be setting up a lot of eCommerce tracking. Basically, I do not want to mess with the good data in the current property.

Would it make sense to keep tracking the primary domain separately and setup another property for cross-domain tracking? Also, am I going to be dealing with any issues because I am running 2 tracking codes for the primary domain?

Answer (score 1):

> Would it make sense to keep tracking the primary domain separately and setup another property for cross-domain tracking?

There is no answer to this question. It totally depends on your analysis needs.

> Also, am I going to be dealing with any issues because I am running 2 tracking codes for the primary domain?

If everything is setup correctly, you shouldn't worry - there won't be issues.